# Parenthesis in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

```
set var= 10(device)
if 1==1 (
echo %var% present
)
```

This batch file is giving error because of the parenthesis after "device".

How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `enabledelayedexpansion` and do `echo !var! present` in the delayed style to prevent the parentheses from being evaluated while echoed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "var= 10(device)"
if 1==1 (
    echo !var! present
)
```

Not directly related to your problem, but I think good advice anyway, whenever you set `variable=string` in batch, enclose the `var=val` pair in quotation marks like this:

```
set "var= 10(device)"
```

This is generally considered proper practice when setting variable=string in batch scripting.  This method allows for other special characters as well, like:

```
set "xml=<device>10</device>"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !xml!
```

Comment: The first part fails, as the problem is not the `set var=10(device)` it's the expansion in `echo %var%` inside the IF block. Therefore you would need `set var= 10 (device^^)` or `set "var= 10 (device^)"`

Comment: Point taken.  I'll reorganize my answer.

Comment: I cannot markup this,because it is giving me error that
"markup requires 15 reputation"